# Hive JDBC program silent hangs as getConnection method does not return

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, hive, thrift

I am trying to access a HIVE table using JDBC driver. When I try to execute the class using maven the execution hangs and stays like it forever on the console. Following is the console output when I try to run the class :-

```
hduser@localhost:~/workspace/FetchHiveData$ mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=HiveJdbcClient
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for FetchHiveData:FetchHiveData:jar:1.0
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.apache.spark:spark-mllib_2.10:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 1.1.0 @ line 54, column 15
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building FetchHiveData 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:java (default-cli) @ FetchHiveData ---
Initialising Connection...********************************
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I have started my Hive thrift server and it is working as I am able to ETL data into it using JSON file.

Here's my class that I am running to connect to HIVE through JDBC :-

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class HiveJdbcClient {
  private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    try {
      Class.forName(driverName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
  System.exit(1);
}
System.out.println("Initialising Connection...********************************"); 
Connection con =   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:9083/default", "", "");
System.out.println("Connection made*******************************");  
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
String tableName = "people_spark_him3";
String sql = "show tables '" + tableName + "'";
System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
if (res.next()) {
  System.out.println(res.getString(1));
}
// describe table
sql = "select * from " + tableName;
System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while (res.next()) {
  System.out.println(res.getString(1) + "\t" + res.getString(2));
}
}
}
```

Here's my POM :-

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-graphx_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-twitter_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-stream</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>HiveJdbcClient</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <optimize>true</optimize>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Try `telnet localhost 9083` first and if it works then we can look further into issue. And second thing how did you start your thrift server?

Comment: I am able to connect by `telnet localhost 9083`.

I started the thriftserver which comes bundled with Spark-1.2.1 using the `SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh` command

Comment: I tried to connect using beeline. But it also hangs after asking username and password 
`beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:9083/default
scan complete in 7ms
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://localhost:9083/default
Enter username for jdbc:hive2://localhost:9083/default: 
Enter password for jdbc:hive2://localhost:9083/default: `

Comment: It seems mllib is added as a dependency twice. But may not be the problem. Also thrift server logs and hive logs may help. Any problems you see on the logs?